# Android change the format of a string representing time and date

Tags: java, android, datetime, date, time

I have the string in the format `ss:mm:hh dd/mm/yyyy` as for example `58:21:16 20/07/2012` but i want the string to be in the format as `dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` as for example `19/Mar/2012 17:34:58`.

But i am getting format as `20:040:2012 02:40:53`.

Here the string i am passing is static.
Anybody having any sort of idea regarding this can help.Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use a capital M for month.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
textView.setText(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

**M** stands for month and **m** for minute.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: the string i am passing is static.

Comment: Did you try the solution? With `mmm`, you are getting minutes, which is why you see the same 40 minutes as 040 in the months place.

Comment: i tried with SimpleDateFormat but got failed.Its not only date format.this is string format and i want string in this format.Read my question again.

Comment: I don't understand. Anyway, I have added the part which prints that string with this dateformat to the answer. That part doesn't change. Same as it was in your question.